# Regex to isolate a specific substring

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string I have retrieved from a File.ReadAllText:

```
6   11 rows processed
```

As you can see there is always an integer specifying the line number in this document. What I am interested in is the integer that comes after it and the words "rows processed". So in this case I am only interested in the substring "11 rows processed".

So, knowing that each line will start with an integer and then some white space, I need to be able to isolate the integer that follows it and the words "rows processed" and return that to a string by itself.

I have been told this is easy to do with Regex, but so far I haven't the faintest clue how to build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you need:

```
\d+(.*)
```

This searches for 1 or more digits (`\d+`) and then it puts everything afterwards in a group:

```
. = any character
* = repeater (zero or more of the preceding value (which is any character in the above
() = grouping
```

However, Jason is correct in that you only need to use a split function

Comment: True. I guess you are right. I just wanted this to be a simple foray into Regex.

Comment: @fullNelson Well, feel free to use it if you really want :-p. As always upvotes/accepted answers are the means of appreciation on SO :D

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regular expressions for this. Just split on the whitespace:

```
var fields = s.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", fields.Skip(1));
```

Here, I am using the fact that if you pass an empty array as the `char []` parameter to `String.Split`, it splits on all whitespace.

Comment: Thank you. I did want to use regex in this case just to start getting familiar with it. +1 for the .NET usage. Should be helpful to someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is done easily with `Regex.Replace()` using the following regular expression...

```
^\d+\s+
```

So it'd be something like this:

```
return Regex.Replace(text, @"^\d+\s+", "");
```

Basically you're just trimming the first number `\d` and the whitespace `\s` that follows.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a Regex it would be like this:

```
string result = null;
Match match = Regex.Match(row, @"^\s*\d+\s*(.*)");
if (match.Success)
    result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

The regex matches from start of row: first spaces if any, then digits and then more spaces.  Last it extracts rest of line and return it as result.

Comment: Thank you for showing some of the .NET code to use Regex. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Example in PHP(C# regex should be compatible):

```
$line = "6 11 rows processed";
$resp = preg_match("/[0-9]+\s+(.*)/",$line,$out);

echo $out[1];
```

I hope I catched your point.